# Highlight words in R list of strings based on term document matrix

Tags: r, dplyr, subset, lookup

The following is a dataframe of campaign data

```
 Subject                  Response Rate(%)     Campaign Type    Channel
  Buy Stunning Phone A        81.00                   A         e-mail
 Special Emi OFFER             81.00                   B            e-mail
 Buy Stunning Phone at EMI     73.00                   C            SMS
The game changer is here.      85.00                   A            SMS
 Buy Stunnig Phone A           80.00                   A            SMS
 Special Emi OFFER             88.00                   B         e-mail
 Buy Stunning Phone at EMI     48.00                   C        e-mail
The game changer is here.      48.00                   A         e-mail
Buy Stunning Phone             89.00                   A         e-mail
 Special Emi OFFER             89.00                   B         SMS
 Buy Stunning Phone at EMI     69.00                   C         SMS
```

I have created a term document matrix as follows

```
    Word    Frequency
     big    10
   upgrade  10
    worth   10
     latest 9
     much   9
    phone   8
 exciting   8
    back    7
  colours   7
    case    6
  stylish   6
   clear    6
experience  5
     time   5
```

I have subsetted the databy dplyr based channel type in order of  decreasing response rates. 
I wish to highlight / list the words of the term document matrix against each subject. If the Word is present in the subject, listed as a separate list near the subject. I am unable to find a way to do this.

Comment: What do you mean by "highlight"?

Comment: Please edit your question and add the code you have used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

do you mean something like this

```
library(dplyr)

df <- read.table(header = TRUE, sep = "," ,text = "Subject,Response Rate(%),Campaign Type,Channel
Buy Stunning Phone A,81.00,A,e-mail
Special Emi OFFER,81.00,B,e-mail
Buy Stunning Phone at EMI,73.00,C,SMS
The game changer is here.,85.00,A,SMS
Buy Stunnig Phone A,80.00,A,SMS
Special Emi OFFER,88.00,B,e-mail
Buy Stunning Phone at EMI,48.00,C,e-mail
The game changer is here.,48.00,A,e-mail
Buy Stunning Phone,89.00,A,e-mail
Special Emi OFFER,89.00,B,SMS
Buy Stunning Phone at EMI,69.00,C,SMS",)


df2 <- read.table(header = TRUE, sep = "," ,text = "Word,Frequency
big,10
upgrade,10
worth,10
latest,9
much,9
phone,8
exciting,8
back,7
colours,7
case,6
stylish,6
clear,6
experience,5
time,5",)

m = sapply(df2$Word %>% as.character() %>% trimws(),regexpr,text = df$Subject %>% as.character(),ignore.case = TRUE)

df$keyWord <- sapply(1:nrow(m),function(idx){
t = m[idx,] > 0 %>% unlist()
paste0(names(t)[t],collapse = ",")
})
df
```

Comment: This Works Well. But the words dont appear to display in the list

Comment: @VishnuRaghavan Hi, sorry their was a bug in the code that appered when you copy and pasted the code. Please try again and see if it works?

Comment: Dear @BBertil Nestorius. It seems to work now. Thank You

Comment: the problem was that `read.table` added a lot of white spaces in-front of the words in `df2`

Comment: Works beautifully. Will try and extend the same to create a set of 2 words ina list per sentence. MAny thanks Again

Comment: @VishnuRaghavan If it helped, please accept the answer. That helps future readers to quicker find what the are looking for...

Comment: Accepted Sir. Apologies for the delay